# Creating through model twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A nested form is doubly creating two of each nested object.

to give you an idea of the schema, the parent Driver has :

`Driver.rb`:

```
  has_many :workables, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :vehicles, through: :workables
```

In the view

```
<%= form_for(driver) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :workables, Workable.new  do |w_form| %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I feel like I'm getting a Heisen-bug, a quantum bug that is sometimes there and sometimes not there. Earlier in the day, I was doubly creating, so I removed the "Workable.new" bit from the field_for helper - this took me back to single creating. Then, recently, the field_for was refusing to render unless I put the Workable.new in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**controller**

```
def new
  @driver = Driver.new
  @driver.workables.build
end
```

**view**

```
<%= form_for(@driver) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :workables  do |w_form| %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```